# How to avoid triggering the "whichKey" menu using Vim bindings in extension's editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set the leader key to "space" and mapped it to trigger my [whichKey](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSpaceCode.whichkey) menu when in Normal Mode. This works without any hiccups in normal editors.

For extensions that open up in the editor, like [ThunderClient](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client), where the VIM bindings do not have any effect, whenever I press <kbd>Space</kbd>, it triggers the `whichKey` menu, which is infuriating.

I tried this on another extension that opens up in the editor and I get the same issue. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

This is my settings.json entry for the normal mode Vim bindings:

```
 "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "<space>"
            ],
            "commands": [
                "whichkey.show"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to check my keybindings.json file. There was a rogue remapping of space key with "nevim" mode rather than "vim". Removed the keybinding and the issue is fixed.

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing a little example code showing the difference. See "[answer]" and its linked pages for more information.